# Getting metadata/column names for empty resultset

Tags: plugin-development, database

I have a dynamically generated sql. How can I know what the column names are, even if the database returns an empty result?

```
$sql = "select t.bar, count(o.foo) as amount
        from craft_table t join craft_otherTable o on t.id = o.id";
$resultset = craft()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true);
```

In Java, i can do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<resultset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
    columnNames.add(resultset.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i))
}
```

I am looking for a similar solution in PHP.

I have tried this:

```
$command = craft()->db->createCommand($sql);
$command->prepare();
var_dump($command->getPdoStatement()->getColumnMeta(0));
```

...but the output is `bool(false)`. I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close - I think the problem was the `$command->prepare()` did not do anything useful, using `$command->query()` executes the query.

This is working for me

```
    $sql = "select t.foo, count(o.bar) as amount from craft_table t join craft_otherTable o on t.id = o.id where 1=0 group by t.foo;"
    $command = craft()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $reader = $command->query($parameters);
    $statement = $command->getPdoStatement();
    $result = [];
    $headers = [];
    for($j=0;$j<$statement->columnCount();$j++){
      $headers[] = $statement->getColumnMeta($j)['name'];
    }
    $result['headers'] = $headers;
    $result['rows'] = $reader->readAll();

    // $result['headers'] is now: ['foo', 'amount']
    // $result['rows'] is now: []
```

Comment: Ohh... nice find.

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty, but the only way I can think of to achieve that behavior is to explicitly check for an empty result set and then run separate `SHOW CREATE TABLE` commands on the tables to grab the column names and add them as keys to the results.

Comment: That could work if i did not use any aliases, but would still require some parsing of the sql to get the specific columns in the select statement.